# Why ng-click not working when i got in $scope.variabel?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have problem, my ngclick not working because i got in $scope.variabel controller.

`<a id="data_table" ng-click="{{ item.target }}"`

I think target can use in ng-click when we call {{ item.target }} but not working, any solution for me ? Thanks

and this is my code :

**Controller**

```
$scope.states = {};
$scope.states.activeItem = 'nav1';

$scope.items = [{
    id: 'nav1',
    target: 'home()',
    title: 'Home',
    icon: 'fa fa-home fa-3x'
}, {
    id: 'nav2',
    target: 'data_1()',
    title: 'Data 1',
    icon: 'fa fa-briefcase fa-3x'
}, {
    id: 'nav3',
    target: 'data_2()',
    title: 'Data 2',
    icon: 'fa fa-briefcase fa-3x'
},
{
    id: 'nav4',
    target: 'data_3()',
    title: 'Data 3',
    icon: 'fa fa-briefcase fa-3x'
},
{
    id: 'nav5',
    target: 'data_4()',
    title: 'Data 4',
    icon: 'fa fa-briefcase fa-3x'
},
{
    id: 'nav6',
    target: 'data_5()',
    title: 'Data 5',
    icon: 'fa fa-briefcase fa-3x'
}];
```

**View**

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'active': item.id == states.activeItem}" ng-click="states.activeItem = item.id">
<a id="data_table" ng-click="{{ item.target }}">
<i class="{{ item.icon }}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<span class="title">{{ item.title }}</span>
<span class="selected"></span>
</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're retrieving data from JSON response from API. I'd say that create a wrapper method `callToAction` in as `target` as in variable name & then call method on `ng-click`.

**Markup**

```
<a id="data_table" ng-click="callToAction(item.target)"

$scope.callToAction = function(actionName){
   $scope[actionName]();
}
```

Comment: Its working!! thanks for help me sir :) Yes, I retrieving data from JSON response from API.

Answer (score 2):

In controller: Update `target: 'home()',` to `target: home,` where home is a function.

In view: Use `ng-click="item.target()"`

Comment: Your code not working , i have error like this : "home is not defined"

Comment: `home` should be a defined function because you want to call it. Where are functions like `home`, `data_1` etc. defined?

Comment: I have tried , my data_1 is defined in $scope.data_1 but still not working

Comment: As it is defined in `$scope.data_1` use `target: $scope.data_1,` to assign the method to object attribute.

Comment: I used target : $scope.data_1 but show error like this : "TypeError: v2.target is not a function"

Comment: Have you updated all `target`s of `$scope.items` to use this pattern `target: $scope.data_1` ?

Answer (score 1):

ng-click **`cannot`** be used with an **`expression`**, call a function and pass the object,

```
ng-click="doSomething(item)"
```

In Controller:

```
$scope.doSomething = function(item){
//do it here
}
```